# Advice on a basic design, first time database design

Tags: mysql, database-design, foreign-key

I am taking a course to become a Java developer.

The course involves using databases but we never really design any, unfortunately.

Most of the time we get pre-made databases and we have to implement code on it to Insert, Update, Read or Delete data.

But when my final test comes, chances are I will be making something that involves a database and therefore I want to try designing a few smaller ones to get the hang of a designing since I noticed that a good database design makes a lot of difference when writing the code to work with it.

I hope these types of questions are allowed here and that it's not going to be too broad.

---

This is a small design I made for something a simple as `clubs` and `members` with `addresses` and `phonenumbers`.

> - There will be multiple clubs.
> - Each club will have multiple members (obvious)
> - A member cannot be part of multiple clubs
> - A member can have multiple phonenumbers and email addresses
> - A member can only have one address
> - An address can belong to different members (couples or siblings)

**My biggest confusions:**

> - If I want to add a column in `Club` that describes the owner, who will also be a member, what is the best approach without having the
>     same member listed twice?
> - Should I put all my tables on the automatic increment of an id or would this be a bad idea? (benefits/downsides?)
> - If I add foreign keys in the foreign keys tab, will these automatically correspond to the correct table or do I have to add
>     these to the columns also? (see picture 2)
> - And my probably noobiest question at all... Do I put the foreign keys of `phonenumber` and `email` in their respective table
>     linking to a person_Id or should I put phoneNumber and email Id's in
>     the person table?

*(My apologies for the language in the pictures not being English, I hope this isn't too much of a problem)*

[image: Design]

[image: Foreign keys]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Responses to your individual questions

> If I want to add a column in `Club` that describes the owner, who will also be a member, what is the best approach without having the same member listed twice?

If —as stated in your specifications— `a Person can be a Member of only one Club`, and you are interested in storing this datum simply as *true or false*, one option is adding a [`BIT(1)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-type.html) or a `BOOLEAN` ([`TINYINT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html)) column to the `Person` table, and you may wish to call this column `IsClubOwner`. In this way, you can register the fact that a determined *person* is a *club owner* exclusively one time. Apart from that, this method also allows the possibility of retaining several *people* as *owners* of the same *club* occurrence. You can see a logical level depiction of this approach in [Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35AqZ.jpg).

However, you are looking for the best approach and, according to my experience, such approach entails the development of a much more expandable and versatile structure. In this respect, follow the progression of a modeling exercise for these and other points below, in the sections entitled “Covering your remaining specifications”, “Person as Member of multiple Clubs” and “Member and Owner as separate entity types”.

> Should I put all my tables on automatic increment of an `id` or would this be a bad idea? (benifits/downsides?)

If you face an **explicit** requirement that indicates the definition of a table with a column of such characteristics, and that column has a **valid contextual meaning** or serves a particular purpose like being a **surrogate** for a **wide** natural PRIMARY KEY (PK), then yes, you should proceed that way.

Otherwise, if you do not have said requirement, I consider it would be **unnecesary** since you have to store and manage a **meaningless extra column** and (perhaps?) also an additional INDEX in your database.

As usual, you have to analyze each case along with its overall repercussions in order to decide how to carry on.

> If I add foreign keys in the foreign keys tab, will these automatically correspond to the correct table or do I have to add these to the columns also?

In this regard, my advice for you is to create your database structure manually, to code your own `DDL` statements until you get a firm grasp of the subject. If you do so, it will be easier for you to understand the processes that graphical tools are performing “under the hood”.

To me, for instance, creating a statement like the following:

```
CONSTRAINT FK_PersonPhoneNumber_to_Person FOREIGN KEY (PersonId)
REFERENCES Person (PersonId)
```

Is much more instructive than using GUI tools to execute this kind of tasks, especially now that you are building your first designs.

> And my probably most noobiest question of all... Do I put the foreign keys of `phone_number` and `email` in their respective table linking to a `person_id` or should I put `phone_number` and `email` `ids` in the person table?

Personally, I think that this and all your other questions are **completely valid** and **well contextualized**.

Returning to the technical aspects that concern us, this precise inquiry offers a good opportunity to review the two following assertions:

- `A Person can be reached through zero-one-or-many PhoneNumbers`
- `A PhoneNumber can be used to reach one-to-many People`

So, one can conclude that there is a many-to-many relationship between `Person` and `PhoneNumber`, therefore, I suggest the creation of an **associative table** named `PersonPhoneNumber` to represent said relationship in your database. The PK of this table should be composed by two different columns: `PersonId` (a FOREIGN KEY [FK] pointing to `Person.PersonId`) and `PhoneNumber` (a FK that makes reference to `PhoneNumber.Number`). For a logical level description of all of the above, see [Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35AqZ.jpg).

On the other hand, let us examine the two propositions that follow:

- `A Person can be contacted via zero-one-or-many EmailAddresses`
- `An EmailAddress can be used to contact exactly one Person`

Then, yes, you should set a FK referencing to `Person` from the `EmailAddress` table, and this table should have a composite PK too, which would be comprised of the columns `PersonId` and `Address`. In this manner, you can ensure that the same combination of `EmailAddress.PersonId` and `EmailAddress.Address` can be inserted only once.

If you also wish to ensure that a given `EmailAddres.Address` can be stored in one sole row, you just have to establish a [UNIQUE CONSTRAINT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/constraint-primary-key.html) for this column.

## Proposed logical data models

In order to expose my suggestions more clearly, I included four distinct **IDEF1X<sup>[1]</sup>** logical models that are shown in [Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35AqZ.jpg), [Figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THYjL.jpg), [Figure 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDZGU.jpg) and [Figure 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feRsJ.jpg). I will provide an explanation of the most relevant features displayed in each one of them in the corresponding sections. You can as well [download from Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yc6dvvtydbxvlmm/Clubs%20and%20Members%20Expository%20Data%20Model.pdf) a PDF that integrates in a single model the majority of the elements under discussion.

## Covering your remaining specifications

#### Relating People and Addresses

Let us inspect the two following (slightly reworded) assertions that are relevant to *people* and *addresses*:

- `A Person can only have one Address`
- `An Address can belong to different People (couples or siblings)`

So, to deal with these restrictions, you may opt to implement a data model similar to the one you can see in [Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35AqZ.jpg).

[image: Fig. 1. Clubs and Members Data Model - First Specifications]

Taking into account the referred model, you should follow the next steps:

1. Create a table called `PersonAddress` fixing a relationship between `Person` and `Address`. Set the columns `PersonId` and `AddressId` as the compound PK of this table.
2. Configure a UNIQUE CONSTRAINT for the `PersonAddress.PersonId` column to ensure that a specific value can be inserted in at most one row of said table. At the logical level, this circumstance implies that `PersonAddress.PersonId` has become an ALTERNATE KEY<sup>**[2]**</sup>.
3. If the value of `AddressId` in a determined `PersonAddress` insertion attempt has not being already stored, then let the insertion continue, otherwise, when such value already exists in a row, you have to check that (a) the `PersonId` who has registered that `AddressId` is also registered as  the `Marriage.WifeId` if the `PersonId` is a male (datum derived via the `Person.GenreCode`) **or** (b) that the `PersonId` is the `Marriage.HusbandId` when the `PersonId` is a female (derived by virtue of `Person.GenreCode`, as well). If one of these conditions is met in the appropiate situation, then you should let the INSERT go on.
4. If the above conditions were not fulfilled, there is still a chance for a `PersonAddress` insertion try to be succesful. You have to check that the `PersonId` value that is involved in said insertion try shares at least one `Progeny.ParentId` with the `PersonId` that has already registered the `PersonAddress.AddressId`. If this condition is satisfied, then it means that they are **stored** as `Siblings` in the database, so this INSERT must succeed.

As in any relational database implementation, you should seriously consider executing your `DML` operations inside [ACID Transactions](http://amturing.acm.org/info/gray_3649936.cfm#add_1) so that you can protect the **integrity** and **consistency** of the data you are working with.

#### Attending the requirements you added in comments: Addresses and Phone Numbers serving equally Clubs and People

On condition that you want to give the chance for *addresses* and *phone numbers* to serve both *people* and *clubs*, you might make use of a **supertype-subtype relationship**. [Here is an answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/92065/help-with-a-scenario-of-music-groups-and-members-in-erd-design/102069#102069) in which I give a more detailed treatment to this kind of structures, in case you are interested.

In the present scenario, you could define `Person` and `Club` as subtypes of a new entity named `Party`, a term commonly used in legal circles to stand for (a) a person or (b) a group of persons (as noted in [sense no. 6](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/party)). With this method, the relationships between `Addresses` (or `PhoneNumbers`) and `People` and `Clubs` would be defined through `Party`, the supertype. See [Figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THYjL.jpg) for a depiction of this suggestion.

[image: Fig. 2. Clubs and Members Data Model - Second Specifications]

**Party and Address**

So we can read in this new model that:

- `A Party keeps zero-one-or-many Addresses`
- `An Address is kept by one-to-many Parties`

Thus, there is a many-to-many relationship involving `Party` and `Address` that is expressed by way of the `PartyAddress` entity.

**Party and PhoneNumber**

Furthermore, we can interpret that:

- `A Party is reached through zero-one-or-many PhoneNumbers`
- `A PhoneNumber is used by one-to-many Parties`

That is why I added the `PartyPhoneNumber` entity that describes the many-to-many association that takes effect between the `Party` and `PhoneNumber` entity types.

**Party and Club or Person**

Then, it can also be read that:

- `A Party is either a Club or a Person`

Hence, `Party` supplies a *connection* from **either** `Clubs` **or** `People` to `Addresses` (or `PhoneNumbers`).

## Person as Member of multiple Clubs

As [@aldwinaldwin](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/68599) mentiones in his answer, if you want to provide the functionality for a *person* to be a *member* of multiple *clubs*, then you can include a table called `ClubMember` that would be acting as another many-to-many relaltionship, this time, naturally, interconnecting `Person` and `Club`.

I am going to add to the above that this table can also be useful in the goal of storing any concrete *person* as *owner* of multiple *clubs*, by means of the inclusion of the already mentioned `IsClubOwner` boolean column. In fact, one can say that this new table is the representation of an integral entity type in its own right.

As demonstrated in [Figure 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDZGU.jpg), such table requires a composite PK made up of the columns `ClubId` and `MemberId` (a **role name<sup>[3]</sup>** given to `PersonId`), and these columns have to be defined also as FKs pointing, correspondingly, to `Club` and `Person`.

[image: Fig. 3. Clubs and Members Data Model - Person as Member of Multiple Clubs]

**A more adaptable structure**

Employing this setting you can also comply with the initial rule that states that `a Person can be a member of only one Club`, but you just have to add a UNIQUE CONSTRAINT to the `MemberId` column, so that a certain value can be entered in no more than one occasion. So, as you can note, this structure is much more adaptable that the one shown in [Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35AqZ.jpg), since by dropping the UNIQUE CONSTRAINT (or INDEX) you would open the aforementioned functionality of permitting a *person* to become a *member* of different *clubs* at the same time.

## Member and Owner as separate entity types

As you know, the storage several facts about the role carried out by a *person* as *owner* of a *club* —besides its mere existance in a *true or false* attribute— can be very advantageous. For example, you may want to keep the *effective date* in which a definite *person* became the  *owner* of a *club*, hence you can manage this situation by introducing a separate entity type called `ClubOwner`, as presented in [Figure 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feRsJ.jpg).

[image: Fig. 4. Clubs and Members Data Model - Member and Owner as Separate Entity Types]

Once you construct a table based on this new entity type, you can add the fitting columns that represent the characteristics that come into play exclusively when a `Person` is the `Owner` of a `Club`. As depicted, this table would hold a PK composed of the FK columns referencing `Person.PersonId` and `Club.ClubId`, this way any combination of `ClubOwner.OwnerId` (or `ClubOwner.PersonId`, if you prefer) and `ClubOwner.ClubId` can be inserted in just one opportunity.

Of course, with this configuration you can still derive in boolean form if a `Person` is the `Owner` of a particular `Club` with the aid of a query that returns a scalar value which can be evaluated to *true or false*.

---

## Notes

<sub>1. Integration Definition for Information Modeling (**[IDEF1X](http://www.idef.com/idef1x.htm)**) is a **highly recommendable data modeling technique** that was defined as a **standard** in december 1993 by the United States National Institute of Standards and Technology (**NIST**). It is solidly based on (a) some of the theoretical papers authored by the **originator** of the **Relational Model**, i.e., [**Dr. E. F. Codd**](http://amturing.acm.org/award_winners/codd_1000892.cfm); on (b) the [**Entity-Relationship theory**](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=320440), developed by [**Dr. P. P. Chen**](http://awards.acm.org/award_winners/chen_6196475.cfm); and also on (c) the **Logical Database Design Technique**, created by **Robert G. Brown**. It is worth noting that IDEF1X was **formalized** by way of **first-order logic**.</sub>

<sub>2. An **ALTERNATE KEY** is an attribute (or a combination of attributes) that holds values that uniquely identify an entity occurrence but was **not chosen** as the PK of the pertinent entity type; each entity type can have zero, one or more ALTERNATE KEYS. In an IDEF1X model, they are are indicated as “AK” plus its respective number, e.g., AK1, AK2, etc. They are usually implemented in a **SQL DDL** structure via a **UNIQUE CONSTRAINT** (or a **UNIQUE INDEX**).</sub>

<sub>3. **Role names** are denotations (or aliases) assigned to FK attributes in order to express the meaning that they hold within the scope of their respective entity. Their usage is recommended since 1970 by **Dr. Codd** in his seminal paper entitled **[“A Relational Model of Data for Large Shared Data Banks”](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=362685)**. For its part, IDEF1X —keeping fidelity regards **relational** practices— also advocates role naming.</sub>

Comment: In the `Addresses and Phone Numbers serving equally Clubs and People` example above: I'm curious why `PartyType` with values of say `P` (person) or `C` (club) is not a column in the `Party` entity. Why does `PartyType` warrant its own table with `PartyTypeCode` column? Feels like type could be a direct attribute of `Party`.

Comment: Does the `PartyType` entity exist only to provide an official "picklist" of acceptable values for say, a client application?

Comment: @SeaDude (a) I'm might be missing something regarding your question, but the diagram contained in *fig. 2* in the "Addresses and Phone Numbers serving equally Clubs and People" section does show a property/attribute named *PartyTypeCode* in the *Party* entity type, so perhaps there's some confusion in that regard. (b) I portray a *PartyType* entity type in the diagram(s) because, in the relevant business context, there exists that type of entity, so including it makes the diagram more illustrative, as it contains all the details of significance.

Comment: @SeaDude (c) In agreement with the point I discussed above, there exists a business-related type of entity named *PartyType*, therefore I would prefer to include the corresponding `PartyType` table in the complementary DDL design, and also a `Party.PartyTypeCode` column constrained as a FK pointing to the PartyType.PartyTypeCode PK. In this manner the DDL layout would reflect all the relevant business-context aspects more accurately.

Comment: @SeaDude Of course, one *could* (d) put the `PartyType` table aside and have, say, a `Party.PartyTypeCode` column that only accepts the values 'P' and 'C' with the aid of a CHECK constraint, but that would not mean that the business scenario doesn't include a *PartyType* entity type with its respective properties, one would have simply decided to skip a few details. So, the `PartyType` table may be deemed *optional* if you will, but the DDL design would be less representative. (e) And yes, the `PartyType` table may work as an official picklist or, as some people like to say, a "look-up" table.

Answer (score 2):

1. If an owner is always a member of his club. Add ownerId to the Club-table, and put the personId in there of the member that is owner.
2. Autoincrement an Id is good. You could add another field 'code', there you put the members code on the club-card in there.
3. Should be automatically ok (i think)
4. Put personId in Phone numbers and email table.

...
You can't be member of multiple clubs?  If you can, create a table ClubMember with clubId and personId. That way you can connect a person to multiple clubs.

Comment: What if i want my club to have a phone number aswel? do i put `clubId` in phonenumber aswell and leave either club or person set to null?

Comment: I would not 'over'-separate all the objects (normalization of data). Just put 1 phone number in the club-table.  Normalization is good, but too much normalization can cause problems.

Comment: but suppose i do want to do this? i'll take address as example, member have an address but clubs will also need an address

Comment: Create an address-record and put the addressId in club.  Because a club has 1 address, a member has 1 address.  For phone numbers, you need to put personId to the phonenumber-record to have 1 to many.   .....    You could make a table   personPhoneNumber(personId,phonenumberId) +  table clubPhoneNumber(clubId, phonenumberId)  what makes it more a many-many-relationship then.