# Is this acceptable practice for a many to many?

Tags: database-design, subtypes, many-to-many

As a newbie in database design, I have a question about many-to-many relationship practice.

This question is actually a follow up question of this [question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/104409/advice-on-a-basic-design-first-time-database-design/104619#104619), but I found it too big to explain in a comment.

The design *should* be like this(picture below):

- A `person` can have multiple `phone numbers`
- A `club` can have multiple `phone numbers`
- A `phone number` can only belong to either 1 `club` or either 1 `person`

As I understand it, this isn't exactly a `many to many` relationship but a `many to one`.
However, `phone number` can belong to 2 other tables.
So, should I add 2 columns to phone numbers then?
1 with a FK to `person` and 1 with a FK to `club`? Leaving one of them `null` when a phone number is entered?

Personally, I thought it was better to work with an extra table `contact` and have `person` and `club` link to this table and then have `phone numbers` link to this table also.

**But,...**
I find myself in the same situation when it comes to e-mail addresses.
So, my idea was to also link them to that same `contact` table.
Was this a good step, or should I have added a separate table for the relationship between `club - email` and `person - email`?

I hope my question is a bit clear considering its actually a follow up.

**-edit-**
My schema seems to be incorrect for what my intentions are.

- a person/club can only have one contact
- a contact can only belong to one person/club
- a phone number can only belong to one contact
- an email address can only belong to one contact
- a contact can have multiple phone numbers
- a contact can have multiple email addresses

[image: Schema]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I notice that your specifications have turned a bit intricate (intentionally, right?), and I consider that this is a beneficial fact since this kind of scenarios will help you broaden your perspective on **relational** design.

Regarding such situation, I am going to suggest you two similar methods to deal with these new conditions. In the first one I propose the use of a **(super)type-subtype cluster**, and in the second one I recommend two **one-to-many relationships**. This way you would be addressing the relationships that you specify between the entities `Person` (or `Club`) and `TelephoneNumber`, and between `Person` (or `Club`) and `EmailAddress`.

## My understanding of your business rules

I will describe my suggestions within the context of your individual questions but, before I do that, you first need to know the way I understand your scenario, and I understand it as follows:

- `Telephone` and `Email` are both types of `ContactMeans`.
- A **particular** type of `ContactMeans` must be fixed for a `Person` (or a `Club`).
- Once a specific type of `ContactMeans` has been fixed for a `Person` (or a `Club`), this `Person` (or `Club`) can be reached through **one-to-many** occurrences of such type of `ContactMeans`, and you want to make sure that **each one** of these occurrences belong to the same type, either `Telephone` or `Email`.

## Proposed methods and answers to your individual questions

### First method

> Personally i thought it was better to work with an extra table `contact` and have `person` and `club` link to this table and then have `phone numbers` link to this table also.
>
> But,...
>
> I find myself in the same situation when it comes to e-mail addresses. So, my idea was to also link them to that same `contact` table. Was this a good step, or should i have added a separate table for the relationship between `club - email` and `person - e mail`?

Yes, adding a separate table is a good step and, to me, the best method, but it needs some refinements. Here is where my first suggestion comes into play, you should make use of **two supertype-subtype clusters**.

In the **first** case, I would include a table called `Party` (which has been mentioned in my other answer). This table will serve the purpose of relating a particular `Club` or `Person` (the `Party` subtypes) with a given `ContactMeans`, `Telephone` or `Email`.

You need to store the fact that a specific `Party` is fixed with only one type of means of contact, so I recommend you including a table called `ContactMeansType`, with a PRIMARY KEY named `ContactMeansTypeCode`. Then, in the `Party` table, you should add a FOREIGN KEY pointing to `ContactMeansType.ContactMeansTypeCode`.

And then comes the **second** supertype-subtype cluster. In this case I would call your `Contact` table “`ContactMeans`” (the supertype of `Telephone` and `Email`) holding a PRIMARY KEY composed of two columns, `PartyId` (FOREIGN KEY referencing `Party.PartyId`) and `ContactMeansNumber`. Every `ContactMeans` must hold a type, so I would add a FOREIGN KEY named `ContactMeansTypeCode` pointing to `ContactMeansType.ContactMeansTypeCode`.

Then, you should establish a validation method in order to guarantee that any given occurrence of a `Party` (`Club` or `Person`) can only be reached through the `ContactMeansType` (`Telephone` or `Email`) that has being fixed for such occurrence. Involve the columns `Party.ContactMeansTypeCode` and `ContactMeans.ContactMeansTypeCode` in this effort. For instance:

- Suppose that a particular `Party` has been fixed to be reached only by means of `Telephone`, then when there is an attempt to INSERT a new `ContactMeans`, you must make sure that the value contained in this `ContactMeans.ContactMeansTypeCode` is the same as the value contained in `Party.ContactMeansTypeCode`, if it is so, then let the INSERT go on, otherwise deny said INSERT attempt. You are using MySQL, so this [content about TRIGGERS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html) from the MySQL Reference Manual may be relevant in this purpose.

See **[Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vr5Sf.png)**, which shows an IDEF1X data model depicting a logical structure for this method.

[image: Fig. 1. Clubs and Members DM - Contact Means First Method]

*** Do not overlooke** the vast power that **relational keys** have to offer, since they are being used to shape most of your business rules.

In this sense, e.g., **it is worth noting** how the PRIMARY KEY called `PartyId` has **migrated** from `Party` to `ContactMeans`, and then from `ContactMeans` to `Telephone` or `Email`. Said PRIMARY KEY has also migrated from `Party` to `Club` or `Person` (receiving the **rolenames** `ClubId` and `PersonId`, respectively), and then to `ClubMember` (`PersonId` being rolenamed as `MemberId`). Thereby, all this “chain” of tables is provided with **referential integrity**.

In this external **[document in .PDF format](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ek49z4jkwyh9fff/Contact%20Means%20for%20Clubs%20and%20Members.pdf?dl=0)** I give a more detailed treatment to this method.

### Second method

> As i understand it, this isn't exactly a `many to many` relation but a `many to one`.
>
> However, `phone number` can belong to 2 other tables. So, should i add 2 columns to phone numbers then? 1 with a FK to `person` and 1 with a FK to `club`? Leaving one of them `null` when a phone number is entered?

Yes, as per the business rules that you have presented, this situation could be handled through a many-to-one (or one-to-many) **relationship**.

And yes, one given `Telephone` can belong to a `Person` or a `Club`. But no, I do not recommend the addition to the `Telephone` table of the two FOREIGN KEYS that make reference to `Person` and `Club`, nor I advise you leaving them `NULL` because, according to my personal experience, this may be a sign that the modeling stage needs to be extended.

Instead of the above, I propose a second method in which, again, you would be using the supertype table called `Party`. This table will “link” `Club` or `Person` with `Telephone` or `Email`.

It is necessary to add a column that represents the fact that a given `Party` has been fixed with a specific type of means of contact, so I would add the column `Party.ContactMeansCode` that makes to the PRIMARY KEY (`ContactMeans.ContactMeansCode`) of a table named `ContactMeans`. Or you could deal with this value by way of a BOOLEAN column called `Party.IsFixedWithEmail` or `Party.IsFixedWithTelephone`, also.

As you can see in **[Figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4T3I.png)**, in this option `Telephone` and `Email` are structured with a **many-to-one** relationship with `Party`, and then, through the latter, to `Club` or `Person`.

I included the column denominated `IsPrimary` to `Telephone` and `Email`, which should be of use to store the fact that an individual `Telephone` (or `Email`) has been established as the main instance (of its corresponding type) for contacting a particular `Party`. Regarding this aspect you must create a method to ensure that there could be only one instance set as primary.

Then, you need to define a procedure to validate that any particular instance of a `Party` (`Club` or `Person`) can only be reached through (or contacted via) the `ContactMeans` (`Telephone` or `Email`) that has being fixed for such instance. The column `Party.ContactMeansCode` is useful in achieving this goal. For example:

- Say an individual `Party` has been fixed to be contacted only via `Email` (
  by virtue of a specific value in the `Party.ContactMeansCode` column), so you have to accept only INSERTS of new `Emails` for such `Party` and, of course, reject every INSERT attempt in the `Telephone` table for this `Party`. Again, since you are using MySQL, you may have to do it via TRIGGERS.

See an IDEF1X data model illustrating a logical structure for this procedure in **[Figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4T3I.png)**.

[image: Fig. 2. Clubs and Members DM - Contact Means Second Method]

In the same external **[document in .PDF format](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ek49z4jkwyh9fff/Contact%20Means%20for%20Clubs%20and%20Members.pdf?dl=0)** I give a more detailed treatment to this second method, as well.

Comment: Again, thank you for such a great answer and for putting so much time into it and even adding an 8 page pdf. I've never seen such great answers , to such standard questions, on any website before. I hope you have a blog or a website or a youtube channel or something but if you don't you should really consider it :p

Comment: @Vahx You are most welcome, it's great to be able to contribute. Yes, I decided to move the “detailed” description to an external .PDF document since it can get kind of tedious inside the answer. I’m honored by your comments. You have presented good questions, backed up with a firm context, so I see them as an excellent oportunity to treat this subjects that I consider fundamental, aiming to provide something of value for you and anyone interested. No, I have none of those, but now that you mention it, I will consider the possibility of creating one. Cheers!

Comment: I just got a badge for 1k views on this question, and i was wondering, did you ever start any blog or youtube channels? :)

Comment: Nope, I haven't created a database-design-related website (or anything of the sort) yet, but I hope some day I will finally have the opportunity to do so; for the time being, I'm focused on contributing to this community when I can :). OTOH, I see that you got the `[Popular Question]` badge for [your two current DBA.SE questions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/57739/vahx?tab=questions), which demonstrates that both are high quality posts.

Comment: Yes, i'm great at asking question, but not as good at answering them :)