# Best index plan for a username column inside an innodb table

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a `username` column in my table: `username VARCHAR(50)` I want to index this column, so I can find a username easily and send messages to users like: "this username has already been taken." So what is the best index plan. the table use innodb engine. Can I use fulltext index?

Comment: Full text indexes are supported for InnoDB since 5.6 version. But you don't need them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Enforcing *username* uniqueness

If you want to enforce *uniqueness* for the values stored in your `username` column and you also have a `user_id` column set up as the PRIMARY KEY (PK) of the relevant table, you might be interested in the implementation of a

- [`UNIQUE` index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html)

for the `username` column.

Such situation implies that, at the *logical level*, the `username` would be an ALTERNATE KEY (AK). An AK is a *column*, or a combination of *columns*, that holds *values* that uniquely identify a certan *row* but was not chosen as the PK of the pertinent *table*; each table can have zero, one or more AKs. As suggested above, they are usually defined in a SQL DDL structure via a UNIQUE constraint which is served, at the *physical level*, by a UNIQUE index.

#### Logical and physical *levels*

As it is *paramount* to distinguish logical from physical aspects when constructing a relational database —independently of the platform of choice—, you might find the concepts and links included in [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/135228/63644) of help.

### Displaying a warning

If you want to display a *message* to the people trying to enter `username` values that have already been taken, you should develop such functionality in the code of the *application programs* that have access to your database.

#### Setting up the length of a column

If you don’t want to allow `username` values with a length greater than 18 characters, then you might like to define the column *size* accordingly, i.e., `VARCHAR(18)`, so you may find of value the following content from the MYSQL reference manual about

- [the `CHAR` and `VARCHAR` Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/char.html),

from which I will stand out the following paragraph:

> The `CHAR` and `VARCHAR` types are declared with a length that indicates the maximum number of characters you want to store. For example, `CHAR(30)` can hold up to 30 characters.

#### Prefix and Fulltext indexes

[@Ypercube](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/993/ypercube%e1%b5%80%e1%b4%b9) has enriched [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/149039/revisions) with responses to your individual questions about some types of indexes:

> Can I use Prefix index?

Technically you could but there is no reason for that. Prefix indexes are rarely - or never - useful in MySQL. If you want to restrict the length of the usernames to 18, the column should be `VARCHAR(18)` and not `(50)`. If you allow only ASCII characters in the *usernames*, the column should have an `ascii` character set and not UTF-8. And even if you keep the `VARCHAR(50)`, the index should still be in the whole column, not a prefix.

> What about a Full Text index?

No, you don’t need them either. Full text indexes are for when one wants to search words or phrases in large texts. Not useful in your case. A simple (unique) B-tree index would be the best.

Comment: I added the username to the primary key as well: 'PRIMARY KEY (user_id, username)' , Now, If I send a query and ask for username only, without user_id, is it still a fast query? You know, because of the message I mention in my question.

Comment: @cool There are some things that I need to know before answering that question: **(1)** To define the situation clearly: You are modeling the *classic* `user` table, right? **(2)** What are all the columns of the table under discussion? **(3)** Is there a particular business rule that demands creating a composite PRIMARY KEY made up of the columns named `user_id` and `username`? **(4)** The column called `user_id` is a *surrogate*, right? -- Once I know those points, I can provide a proper answer.

Comment: (1) Yes, it's a ordinary user table. (2) The columns are `user_id , username, password, security_question, answer, date_of_registration, school_id` . (3) I'm not sure if I understand the question but I have a leader board that every user can see, and I don't want they have similar names. (4) Yes user_id is a surrogate key.

Comment: @cool Ok, very good. Now, clarifying question **(4)** is very important because a relational database is supossed to reflect the business context of interest with **accuracy**, so that's why I need to know if there is a particular *business rule* that you are representing by means of the implementation of the primary key (PK) made up of the combination of `user_id` and `username`. So, to put it another way: Why did you decide to define the PK of the `user` table in that way? Is there a particular reason for doing so (perhaps, a real business aspect or, maybe, a personal preference)?

Comment: thank you for your time. **Why did you decide to define the PK of the user table in that way?** at first I decided to define an id for every user, and use that id as a foreign key in other table (3 other tables), then I realize that I don't like users to have same usernames because of the leaderboard thing I mentioned, I thought maybe using `unique index` would help, but then in my registration page I wanted to add this feature to message the user for duplicate username and ask him to change it. so I suppose I should have a quick answer from server.

Comment: Summary: I need an id column to use it as a foreign key, it should be unique, I need the username to be unique, for my leaderboard, and I send queries that uses the username only and also queries which only use id. Like `SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '{$username}' LIMIT 1` and other queries like this: `SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id = {$user_id} LIMIT 1`

Comment: @cool You are welcome. So, as I mentioned in the answer body, [this post](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/135228/63644) where I discuss some relational topics (e.g. logical vs. physical aspects, key identification and declaration, capturing meaning, database design, etc.) is quite relevant to this situation and might help you to avoid future problems of a similar kind.

Comment: @cool As for the definition of the `user` PK made up of `user_id` and `username`, you should not proceed that way as it is not a real PK because it would not enforce uniqueness for each of the columns individually, so that combination of columns should not be declared as the PK. Instead, you should leave `user_id` as the PK (aided, physically, by its individual index), and set `username` with a UNIQUE constraint (served, physically, by its own INDEX, which protects uniqueness and, at the same time, enhances speed retrieval), as it is, logically, an ALTERNATE KEY.

Comment: The `user_id` column should be used, as you rightly mentioned, for FK references from (or to) other tables, (e.g., it might be a FK that references `person.person_id`) and its PK index might make it, physically, a little faster than the `username`'s one regarding queries, but the index of the UNIQUE constraint fixed to `username` should be quite fast as well. So, both indexes should behave quite well depending on the server and hardware configurations, network speed, etc.

Comment: In this situation, the `username` ALTERNATE KEY is a natural key that is made up of real data. The `user_id` surrogate (which you specified) should be meaningless and system generated value that, by itself does not provide *row meaning uniqueness*, so it is necessary to find a natural key (`username` in this case), and declare it properly so that the platform can protect the meaning uniqueness of each row. Surrogates should be used only in specific cases as they have to be implemented as an extra column and very likely and additional index, which has physical and logical repercussions, etc.