# Database schema for entities with two possible owner/parent types?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, schema, subtypes

I'm using PostgreSQL with [Sequelize](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize) as my ORM.

I have one type, `User`. The second type is `Group`, which can have any number of users associated with it through a `GroupMemberships` table. `User`s can also own any number of `Group`s.

My third type, `Playlist`, can belong to either a `User` OR a `group`. What would be the best way to design a schema for this type so that it can have either one type of owner or the either?

My first pass I created both associations, but only populated one at a time. This could possibly work, but seems hacky and makes queries difficult.

**Additional information**

Here are my responses to the clarification requests posted by MDCCL via comments:

> (1) If a *Playlist* is owned by a given *Group*, one can say that this *Playlist* is related to one-to-many *Users*, as long as they are *Members* of such *Group*, right?

I believe this is technically true, but this one-to-many association does not exist explicitly.

> (2) So, is it possible for a specific *Playlist* to be owned by one-to-many *Groups* at the same time?

No, it should not be possible for a `Playlist` to be owned by one-to-many `Groups`.

> (3) Is it possible for a particular *Playlist* to be owned by one-to-many *Groups* and, at the same time, by one-to-many *Users* who are not *Members* of such *Group*?

No, because as in (2) a one-to-many from `Playlist` to `Group` should not exist. Additionally, if a `Playlist` is owned by a `Group` it is not owned by a `User`, and vice versa. Only one owner at a time.

> (4) What are the properties used to uniquely identify a *Group*, a *User* and a *Playlist*?

They each have a surrogate primary key (`id`), as well as a natural key (though not primary). These are `slug` for `Group` and `Playlist`, and `username` for `User`.

> (5) Could a particular *Playlist* suffer an *Owner* change?

Although I don't plan on this being a feature (at least initially), I suppose this could hypothetically occur.

> (6) What’s the meaning of the *Group.Slug* and *Playlist.Slug* attributes? Are their values stable enough to be defined as primary keys or do they change very often? The values of these two properties, along with *User.Username* must be unique, correct?

These `slug`s are unique, lowercase, hyphenated versions of their respective entity's `title`. For example, a `group` with the `title` 'Test Group' would have the `slug` 'test-group'. Duplicates are appended with incremental integers. This would change any time their `title` changes. I believe that means they wouldn't make great primary keys? Yes, `slugs` and `usernames` are unique in their respective tables.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understand your specifications properly, your scenario involves —among other significant aspects— a *supertype-subtype* structure.

I will exemplify below how to (1) model it at the *conceptual* level of abstraction and subsequently (2) represent it in a *logical-level* DDL design.

## Business rules

The following conceptual formulations are among the most important rules in your business context:

- A *Playlist* is owned by either exactly one *Group* or exactly one *User* at a specific point in time
- A *Playlist* may be owned by one-to-many *Groups* or *Users* at distinct points in time
- A *User* owns zero-one-or-many *Playlists*
- A *Groups* owns zero-one-or-many *Playlists*
- A *Group* is made up of one-to-many *Members* (who must be *Users*)
- A *User* may be a *Member* of zero-one-or-many *Groups*.
- A *Group* is made up of one-to-many *Members* (who must be *Users*)

As the associations or relationships (a) between *User* and *Playlist* and (b) between *Group* and *Playlist* are quite alike, this fact reveals that *User* and *Group* are *mutually exclusive* entity subtypes of *Party*<sup>**1**</sup>, which is in turn their entity supertype —supertype-subtype clusters are classic data structures that come about in conceptual schemas of very diverse sorts—. In this manner, two new rules can be asserted:

- A *Party* is categorized by exactly one *PartyType*
- A *Party* is either a *Group* or a *User*

And four of the previous rules must be reformulated as only three:

- A *Playlist* is owned by exactly one *Party* at a specific point in time
- A *Playlist* may be owned by one-to-many *Parties* at distinct points in time
- A *Party* owns zero-one-or-many *Playlists*

**Expository IDEF1X diagram**

The IDEF1X<sup>**2**</sup> diagram shown in [Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QH1sK.png) consolidates all of the aforementioned business rules along with other ones that appear pertinent:

[image: Figure 1 - Playlist Owners IDEF1X Diagram]

As demonstrated, *Group* and *User* are portrayed as subtypes that are connected by the respective lines and the *exclusive* symbol with *Party*, the supertype.

The *Party.PartyTypeCode* property stands for the subtype *discriminator*, i.e., it indicates which kind of subtype instance must supplement a given supertype occurrence.

Also, *Party* is connected with *Playlist* via the *OwnerId* property which is depicted as a FOREIGN KEY that points to *Party.PartyId*. In this way, *Party* interrelates (a) *Playlist* with (b) *Group* and (c) *User*.

Accordingly, since a particular *Party* instance is either a *Group* or a *User*, a specific *Playlist* can be linked with at most one subtype occurrence.

## Illustrative logical-level layout

The IDEF1X diagram expounded before has served me as a platform to create the following logical SQL-DDL arrangement (and I have supplied notes as comments highlighting several points of particular relevance —e.g., the constraint declarations—):

```
-- You should determine which are the most fitting 
-- data types and sizes for all your table columns 
-- depending on your business context characteristics.

-- Also, you should make accurate tests to define the 
-- most convenient INDEX strategies based on the exact 
-- data manipulation tendencies of your business domain.

-- As one would expect, you are free to utilize 
-- your preferred (or required) naming conventions. 

CREATE TABLE PartyType ( -- Represents an independent entity type.
    PartyTypeCode CHAR(1)  NOT NULL,
    Name          CHAR(30) NOT NULL,  
    --
    CONSTRAINT PartyType_PK PRIMARY KEY (PartyTypeCode),
    CONSTRAINT PartyType_AK UNIQUE      (Name)  
);

CREATE TABLE Party ( -- Stands for the supertype.
    PartyId         INT       NOT NULL,
    PartyTypeCode   CHAR(1)   NOT NULL, -- Symbolizes the discriminator.
    CreatedDateTime TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,  
    --
    CONSTRAINT Party_PK            PRIMARY KEY (PartyId),
    CONSTRAINT PartyToPartyType_FK FOREIGN KEY (PartyTypeCode)
        REFERENCES PartyType (PartyTypeCode)
);

CREATE TABLE UserProfile ( -- Denotes one of the subtypes. 
    UserId     INT      NOT NULL, -- To be constrained as both (a) the PRIMARY KEY and (b) a FOREIGN KEY.
    UserName   CHAR(30) NOT NULL,  
    FirstName  CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    LastName   CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    GenderCode CHAR(3)  NOT NULL,
    BirthDate  DATE     NOT NULL,
    --
    CONSTRAINT UserProfile_PK  PRIMARY KEY (UserId),
    CONSTRAINT UserProfile_AK1 UNIQUE ( -- Multi-column ALTERNATE KEY.
        FirstName,
        LastName,
        GenderCode,
        BirthDate
    ),
    CONSTRAINT UserProfile_AK2       UNIQUE (UserName), -- Single-column ALTERNATE KEY.
    CONSTRAINT UserProfileToParty_FK FOREIGN KEY (UserId)
        REFERENCES Party (PartyId)
);

CREATE TABLE MyGroup ( -- Represents the other subtype.
    GroupId INT      NOT NULL, -- To be constrained as both (a) the PRIMARY KEY and (b) a FOREIGN KEY.
    Title   CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    --
    CONSTRAINT Group_PK        PRIMARY KEY (GroupId),
    CONSTRAINT Group_AK        UNIQUE      (Title), -- ALTERNATE KEY.
    CONSTRAINT GroupToParty_FK FOREIGN KEY (GroupId)
        REFERENCES Party (PartyId)
);

CREATE TABLE Playlist ( -- Stands for an independent entity type.
    PlaylistId      INT       NOT NULL,
    OwnerId         INT       NOT NULL,  
    Title           CHAR(30)  NOT NULL,
    CreatedDateTime TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,  
    --
    CONSTRAINT Playlist_PK     PRIMARY KEY (PlaylistId),
    CONSTRAINT Playlist_AK     UNIQUE      (Title),  -- ALTERNATE KEY.
    CONSTRAINT PartyToParty_FK FOREIGN KEY (OwnerId) -- Establishes the relationship with (a) the supertype and (b) through the subtype with (c) the subtypes.
        REFERENCES Party (PartyId)
);

CREATE TABLE GroupMember ( -- Denotes an associative entity type.
    MemberId       INT       NOT NULL, 
    GroupId        INT       NOT NULL,
    IsOwner        BOOLEAN   NOT NULL,    
    JoinedDateTime TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    --        
    CONSTRAINT GroupMember_PK              PRIMARY KEY (MemberId, GroupId), -- Composite PRIMARY KEY.
    CONSTRAINT GroupMemberToUserProfile_FK FOREIGN KEY (MemberId)
        REFERENCES UserProfile (UserId),
    CONSTRAINT GroupMemberToMyGroup_FK     FOREIGN KEY (GroupId)
        REFERENCES MyGroup (GroupId)  
);
```

Of course, you can make one or more adjustments so that all the characteristics of your business context are represented with the needed precision in the actual database.

*Note*: I have tested the above logical layout on [this db<>fiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=8c63b7a1afaf3aef6a56922c66ebd9e8) and also on [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ea2dd), both “running” on PostgreSQL 9.6, so that you can see them “in action”.

**The Slugs**

As you can see, I did not include `Group.Slug` nor `Playlist.Slug` as columns in the DDL declarations. This is so because, in agreement with your following explanation

> These `slug`s are unique, lowercase, hyphenated versions of their respective entity's `title`. For example, a `group` with the `title` 'Test Group' would have the `slug` 'test-group'. Duplicates are appended with incremental integers. This would change any time their `title` changes. I believe that means they wouldn't make great primary keys? Yes, `slugs` and `usernames` are unique in their respective tables.

one can conclude that their values are *derivable* (i.e., they must be computed or calculated in terms of the corresponding `Group.Title` and `Playlist.Title` values, sometimes in conjunction with —I assume, some kind of system-generated— INTEGERs), so I would not declare said columns in any of the *base* tables as they would introduce update irregularities.

In contrast, I would produce the `Slugs`

- maybe, in a *view*, which (a) includes the derivation of such values in *virtual* columns and (b) can be used directly in further SELECT operations —appending the INTEGER part could be obtained, e.g., by combining the value of (1) the `Playlist.OwnerId` with (2) the intermediate hyphens and (3) the value of the `Playlist.Title`;
- or, by virtue of application program code, mimicking the approach described before (perhaps procedurally), once the pertinent data sets are retrieved and formatted for end-user interpretation.

In this manner, any of those two methods would avoid the “update synchronization” mechanism that ought to be put in place *iff* the `Slugs` are retained in columns of base tables.

**Integrity and consistency considerations**

It is critical to mention that (i) *each* `Party` row must be complemented *at all times* by (ii) the respective counterpart in *exactly one* of the tables standing for the subtypes, which (iii) must “comply with” the value contained in the `Party.PartyTypeCode` column —denoting the discriminator—.

It would be quite advantageous to enforce that kind of situation in a *declarative* manner, but none of the major SQL database management systems (including Postgres) has supplied the *necessary* instruments to proceed like that; therefore, writing *procedural* code within [ACID TRANSACTIONS](http://amturing.acm.org/info/gray_3649936.cfm#add_1) is so far the best option to guarantee that the circumstances previously described are *always* met in your database. Other possibility would be resorting to TRIGGERS, but they are prone to make things untidy, so to speak.

## Comparable cases

If you want to establish some analogies, you might be interested in taking a look at my answers to the (newer) questions entitled

- “[Designing a database for a funds transfers business context](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/179712/63644)” and
- “[Modeling a scenario in which each Music Artist is either a Group or a Solo Performer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/102069/63644)”,

since comparable scenarios are discussed.

---

## Endnotes

<sub><sup>**1**</sup> *Party* is a term used in legal contexts when referring to either an *individual* or a *group of individuals that compose a single entity*, so this denomination is suitable to represent the concepts of *User* and *Group* with respect to the business environment in question.</sub>

<sub><sup>**2**</sup> *Integration Definition for Information Modeling* ([IDEF1X](http://www.idef.com/idef1x-data-modeling-method/)) is a highly recommendable data modeling technique that was established as a *standard* in December 1993 by the United States *National Institute of Standards and Technology* (NIST). It is solidly based on (a) some of the early theoretical works authored by the sole originator of the [relational model](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=362685), i.e., [Dr. E. F. Codd](http://amturing.acm.org/award_winners/codd_1000892.cfm); on (b) the [entity-relationship view](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=320440), developed by [Dr. P. P. Chen](http://awards.acm.org/award_winners/chen_6196475.cfm); and also on (c) the Logical Database Design Technique, created by Robert G. Brown.</sub>