# Confused about what to use to create the data

Tags: database-recommendation, subtypes

I want to create a database for myself. The data has complex grouping. I don't know which system to use to create my database. The data is in groups and sub-group forms, it almost has 5-6 layers of subgroups. I tried SQL but such complex sub-groups are not possible in it.

I really need to create the database. Hope for some good advice.
[image]

This is the type of grouping I want to do and I am searching for a kind of system that can save such data in a way that when I want to filter the data to find something I can get the results.

EG: if I search for high toughness properties of a material then MS and high carbon steel should appear.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for updating your question. It is the weekend now, which is typically a quieter time, but while you're waiting for a specific answer, you might like to review answers in the "subtypes" category (click on the tag I added) like [this answer for example](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/107969/1192).

Comment: What database are you using?  Your scenario doesn't look  that complex  to me. I don't see why you can't use SQL. Depending upon volume of data and performance required you could do it with a single table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/)'s [inheritance](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/tutorial-inheritance.html) feature.