# Modelling an entity-relationship diagram for a scenario involving companies, services, and clients

Tags: database-design, erd, database-diagrams

I am creating an entity-relationship diagram (ERD) for managing workflow and other details of Company X in which I am maintaining details of the following objects:

- Employees of Company X
- Services offered by Company X
- Employees of Company X Associated with the services
- Company X's Employee Multiple Mobile Numbers
- Employee Multiple Addresses
- Employee Multiple Email ID (One Default)
- Account of Employee
- Request for Service from Client
- Client Information

I have created the following ERD until now.

[image: ER Diagram]

Entitiy types and their Purpose:

- Person entity type to store details of the person
- Employee entity type to store details of employee.
- Service entity type to store details of services
- Service Associated entity type to store details of which Employee is associated with which Service
- Mobile Number entity type to store any Mobile Number
- Address entity type to store the Address of any Person
- Email ID entity type to store Email Id of any Person
- Service Request to store details of Service requested

Now I want to store the details of the Client.

A client could be of two type:

- Individual
- Company

If the Client is an Individual, any Person can request for a Service.

If the Client is a Company, a Person will request on behalf of the Company say this Company Employee.

So, we want to store information of Individual Client i.e. Name, PAN Number, Mobile Number, Email ID, Request Details,

And other information is Details about company i.e. Company Name, PAN Number, Address, Requests,

And Employee of this Company who is requesting on behalf of a Company i.e Name, Email ID, Mobile Numbers, Request Requested.

NOTE: I am working alone on this project and teachers are not helping me much. I am creating a database design for the first time by learning online from various resources. Your guidance will be helpful to me. Thank You.

Does anyone could clear me where that information will store.

Should I make a new entity type for storing Company Y employee details or should I add them in person entity type and connect it with the client company entity type?

And how should I store individual client information?

Is there any mistake in the ERD?

Comment: As per the aspect about a *Client* being either a *Company* or an *Individual*, you may find of help some of the concepts detailed in [Q & A no. 1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/179712/63644), [Q & A no. 2](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/107969/63644) and [Q & A no. 3](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/102069/63644).