# Entity Relationship to One of Several Other Entities

Tags: database-design

I'm building a database model that requires one table to have a relationship to only one of several other tables. For example, a `Contract` may be associated with a `Person`, a `Business`, or a `Government`, but only one of those.

Other than having a foreign key column for each of those and using a check constrain to ensure only one is populated, what is the best approach to this situation?

Comment: it should be good enough. But I'm thinking 'bout having one table stands for Person/Business/Goverment called Tender, it has Type which is Person or Bussiness or Goverment, and then Contract will have FK to Tender only.

Comment: @datnguyen, I prefer the supertype variant which you describe as Tender. I think you should make it an answer

Comment: How would that work if those entities are completely different and and not really suptypes of a class, other than this one relationship?

Comment: @tim: In that case, you may have PersonExtraInfo, BusineesExtraInfo and GovermentExtraInfo tables to contains the diff info. Tender would have the common info of them, and I don't think there would be an entity that was not really suptypes of Tender. In case you'd like not to have 3 extra tables, like to denormalize it, you could put all info together in Tender.

Comment: @tim You may find of help the design principles detailed [in this  Q & A](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/107969/63644) and [in this  Q & A](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/179712/63644).