# Designing a generic associative table

Tags: database-design, foreign-key

I need the ability to associate two entities of the same ***or*** different types. Take the concept of planes and trucks that have the ability to radio to each other.

```
+----------------------+
|        Airplane      |
+----------------------+
| AirplaneId           |
| Wingspan             |
| MaxTakeoffWeight     |
| etc...               |
+----------------------+

+----------------------+
|         Truck        |
+----------------------+
| TruckId              |
| CargoCubicFt         |
| IsResidential        |
| etc...               |
+----------------------+

+----------------------+
| CommunicationBetween |
+----------------------+
| [AirplaneOrTruckId]  |
| [AirplaneOrTruckId]  |
+----------------------+
```

What's the best way to accomplish these associations?

#### Notes

I can't combine or abstract out the two entities (e.g. can't combine planes and trucks into a Vehicles table) because each entity has many unique properties that the other doesn't have.

The only other idea I have is to create a table like this:

```
+----------------------+
| CommunicationBetween |
+----------------------+
| Entity1              | -- "Airplane" or "Truck"
| Id1                  | -- AirplaneId or TruckId
| Entity2              | -- "Airplane" or "Truck"
| Id2                  | -- AirplaneId or TruckId
+----------------------+
```

... but that's not an elegant solution.

Comment: Among other related points, the excerpt *"I can't combine or abstract out the two entities (e.g. can't combine planes and trucks into a Vehicles table) because each entity has many unique properties that the other doesn't have."* suggests that representing the scenario with the aid of a conceptual *supertype-subtype* relationship would be very advantageous. Establishing some analogies, you may find of help [Q & A no. 1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/179712/63644) and [Q & A no. 2](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/107969/63644) in that regard.

Comment: @MDCCL Hmm, maybe it would be best to establish `Vehicle` and `VehicleType` tables then. Your Party-Person-Organization example applies well to my scenario. Thanks for helping me think that through!