# Developing a database for a funds transfers business where (a) people and organizations can (b) send and receive money

Tags: postgresql, database-design, subtypes

In the business context of relevance, both *members* and *organizations* need to have an *account* for *funds*. *Funds* can be *transferred*

- from *member* to *member*,
- from *member* to *organization*,
- from *organization* to *organization*, and
- from *organization* to *member*.

**Considerations**

In order to build a database for such a scenario, I have created the following three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Members ( 
  memberid serial primary key, 
  name varchar(50) unique, 
  passwd varchar(32), 
  account integer 
);

CREATE TABLE Organizations (  
  organizationid serial primary key, 
  name varchar(150) unique, 
  administrator integer references Members(memberid), 
  account integer 
);

CREATE TABLE TransferHistory  
  "from" integer, -- foreign key?
  "to" integer, -- foreign key?
  quantity integer 
);
```

I think that the `TransferHistory` table is necessary to show *who/what* sent *funds* to *whom/what*.

The problem is, since `Members` and `Organizations` are different tables, how can I reference them from the `TransferHistory` table?

For instance, the data involved can show up as follows:

```
Account      Account      Quantity
-----------  -----------  --------
 1072561733  38574637847       500
38574637847   1072561733       281
```

That would suggest that *accounts* need to be recorded in the same table, but *accounts* are for two different kinds of *owners* (*members* and *organizations*), each of which are retained in their respective table.

I could create a table called `Accounts`, so now I would have four tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Members (
  memberid serial primary key, 
  name varchar(50) unique, 
  passwd varchar(32), 
  accountid integer references Accounts(accountid) 
);

CREATE TABLE Organizations (
  organizationid serial primary key, 
  name varchar(150) unique, 
  administrator integer references Members(memberid), 
  accountid integer references Accounts(accountid)
);

CREATE TABLE Accounts ( 
  accountid serial primary key, 
  state integer 
);

CREATE TABLE TransferHistory ( 
  "from" integer references Accounts(accountid), 
  "to" integer references Accounts(accountid), 
  quantity integer 
);
```

...but now I have to ensure that each foreign key from `Members` and `Organizations` tables does not point to the same `Account` row in `Accounts` table...

...or I could have an `Accounts` table having two foreign keys, one pointing to `Members` and another to `Organizations` (and one foreign key column would have to contain a NULL mark at all times). But now things get a bit confusing with respect to queries. The database design would be, generally speaking, as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Members ( 
  memberid serial primary key, 
  name varchar(50) unique, 
  passwd varchar(32) 
);

CREATE TABLE Organizations (
  organizationid serial primary key, 
  name varchar(150) unique, 
  administrator integer references Members(memberid) 
);

CREATE TABLE Accounts ( 
  accountid serial primary key, 
  member integer references Members(memberid), 
  organization integer references Organizations(organizationid),
  state integer 
);

CREATE TABLE TransferHistory ( 
  "from" integer references Accounts(accountid), 
  "to" integer references Accounts(accountid), 
  quantity integer 
);
```

So, does anybody have a suggestion on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If the intention is to build a *relational* database, it is really helpful to first carry out (a) an analysis of the business context of interest —in order to delineate a *conceptual* schema— in terms of *entity types*, inspecting their *properties* and *associations* before (b) thinking in terms of tables, columns and constraints —aspects that correspond to the *logical* level—. Following this course of action, it is much simplier to capture the *meaning* of the business domain with accuracy and then *reflect* it in an actual, well constrained, SQL-DDL design.

One of the numerous advantages offered by the [relational paradigm](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=362685) is that it permits managing the data in its natural structure; hence one has to “find” such structure before employing relational instruments to manage it. It does not matter if the scenario at issue is related to a personal project (as you pointed out via comments): the more realistic you define it, the more you will learn from its development (if that is the purpose of this effort). Of course, a realistic personal project may evolve into a comercial one with relatively minor adaptations.

## Business rules

In order to present a first progression that you may like to use as a reference, I have formulated some of the conceptual-level business rules that are among the most significant ones, and they are enumerated as follows:

- A *Person* owns zero-one-or-many *Accounts*
- A *Person* is primarily distinguished by its *Id*
- A *Person* is alternately distinguished by his/her *Firstname*, *Lastname*, *BirthDate* and *Gender*
- An *Organization* owns zero-one-or-many *Accounts*
- An *Organization* is primarily differentiated by its *Id*
- An *Organization* is alternately differentiated by its *Name*
- An *Organization* starts operating at a *FoundingDate*
- An *Account* is the *Transferor* in zero-one-or-many *Transfers*
- An *Account* is the *Transferee* in zero-one-or-many *Transfers*
- An *Account* is primarily identified by its *Number*
- An *Account* is issued at an exact *CreatedDate*
- In a *Transfer*, the *Transferor* must be different from the *Transferee*
- A *Person* may log in via zero-or-one *UserProfile*

Since the associations —or relationships— (1) between *Person* and *Account* and (2) between *Organization* and *Account* are very similar, this fact reveals that *Person* and *Account* are entity *subtypes* of *Party* (basically, *either* an individual *or* a group of individuals), which is in turn their entity *supertype*. This is a classic information structure that arises very frequently in multiple conceptual models of diverse kinds. In this manner, two new rules can be asserted:

- A *PartyType* classifies zero-one-or-many *Parties*
- A *Party* is either a *Person* or an *Organization*

And two of the previous business rules can be consolidated into a single one:

- A *Party* owns zero-one-or-many *Accounts*

Which can be also be stated from the point of view of the *Account* entity type:

- An *Account* is owned by exactly-one *Party*

### Expository IDEF1X diagram

Consequently, I created an expository (simplified) IDEF1X<sup>**†**</sup> diagram that synthesizes the rules formulated above, and it is shown in [Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwE73.png):

[image: Figure 1 - Funds Transfer IDEF1X Model]

**Party, Person and Organization: Supertype-subtype structure**

As demonstrated, `Person` and `Organization` are depicted as *mutually exclusive* subtypes of `Party`.

The `Party` supertype holds a *discriminator* (i.e., `PartyTypeCode`) and all the properties (or attributes) that are common to its subtypes, which, in turn, have the properties that apply to each of them.

**Account**

The `Account` entity type is directly connected with `Party`, which provides a subsequent connection between (i) `Account` and `Person`, and between (ii) `Account` and `Organization`.

Since it is possible that, in the real world, (a) a bank `Account` is not transferable, i.e., its `Owner` cannot change and (b) an `Account` cannot start being current or enabled without an `Owner`, the PRIMARY KEY of this entity type *may* be comprised of the properties `PartyId` *and* `AccountNumber`, so you should analyze the scenario even more thoroughly to define this point with high precision.

**Transfer**

On the other hand, the `Transfer` entity type presents a composite PRIMARY KEY made up of three properties, i.e., `TransferorAccountNumber`, `TransfereeAccountNumber` (*role names* I assigned to distinguish every one of two `Account` properties involved in each `Transfer` instance) and `TransferDateTime` (which tells the exaxct *Instant* when a `Transfer` occurrence was performed).

**Factors about AccountNumbers**

Be also aware that, in actual banking systems, the format of an `AccountNumber` data point is usually more complex than a “mere” integer value. There are different format arrangements, e.g., the one that corresponds to the International Bank Account Number (IBAN), defined by the [ISO 13616](https://www.iso.org/standard/41031.html) standard. This aspect implies, evidently, that the (1) conceptual analysis and the later (2) logical definitions require a much more exhaustive approach.

### Illustrative logical SQL-DDL declarations

Then, as a derivation from the previous analysis, I have declared a logical design where

- each *table* represents an entity type,
- each *column* stands for a property of the respective entity type, and
- multiple constraints are set up (declaratively) in order to guarantee that the assertions in form of *rows* retained in all the tables comply with the business rules determined at the conceptual tier.

I have supplied notes as comments that explain some of the features that I esteem particularly important with respect to the aforementioned structure, that is shown below:

```
-- You have to determine which are the most fitting 
-- data types and sizes for all your table columns 
-- depending on the business context characteristics.

-- Also, you should make accurate tests to define the
-- most convenient physical implementation settings; e.g.,
-- a good INDEXing strategy based on query tendencies.

-- As one would expect, you are free to make use of 
-- your preferred (or required) naming conventions. 

CREATE TABLE PartyType (
    PartyTypeCode CHAR(1)  NOT NULL, -- This one is meant to contain the meaningful values 'P', for 'Person', and 'O' for 'Organization'.
    Name          CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    --
    CONSTRAINT PartyType_PK PRIMARY KEY (PartyTypeCode)
);

CREATE TABLE Party ( -- Represents the supertype.
    PartyId         INT       NOT NULL,
    PartyTypeCode   CHAR(1)   NOT NULL, -- Denotes the subtype discriminator.
    CreatedDateTime TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,  
    Etcetera        CHAR(30)  NOT NULL,  
    --
    CONSTRAINT Party_PK            PRIMARY KEY (PartyId),
    CONSTRAINT PartyToPartyType_FK FOREIGN KEY (PartyTypeCode)
        REFERENCES PartyType (PartyTypeCode)
);

CREATE TABLE Person ( -- Stands for a subtype.
    PersonId        INT      NOT NULL, -- To be CONSTRAINed as PRIMARY KEY and FOREIGN KEY at the same time, enforcing an association cardinality of one-to-zero-or-one from Party to Person.
    FirstName       CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    LastName        CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    GenderCode      CHAR(3)  NOT NULL,
    BirthDate       DATE     NOT NULL,
    Etcetera        CHAR(30) NOT NULL,  
    --
    CONSTRAINT Person_PK        PRIMARY KEY (PersonId),
    CONSTRAINT Person_AK        UNIQUE ( -- Composite ALTERNATE KEY.
        FirstName,
        LastName,
        GenderCode,
        BirthDate
    ),
    CONSTRAINT PersonToParty_FK FOREIGN KEY (PersonId)
        REFERENCES Party (PartyId)
);

CREATE TABLE Organization ( -- Represents the other subtype.
    OrganizationId  INT      NOT NULL, -- To be CONSTRAINed as PRIMARY KEY and FOREIGN KEY simultaneously, enforcing a association cardinality of one-to-zero-or-one from Party to Organization.
    Name            CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    FoundingDate    DATE     NOT NULL,
    Etcetera        CHAR(30) NOT NULL,  
    --
    CONSTRAINT Organization_PK        PRIMARY KEY (OrganizationId),
    CONSTRAINT Organization_AK        UNIQUE      (Name), -- ALTERNATE KEY.
    CONSTRAINT OrganizationToParty_FK FOREIGN KEY (OrganizationId)
        REFERENCES Party (PartyId)
);

CREATE TABLE UserProfile (
    UserId          INT       NOT NULL, -- To be CONSTRAINed as PRIMARY KEY and FOREIGN KEY at the same time, enforcing an association cardinality of one-to-zero-or-one from Person to UserProfile.
    UserName        CHAR(30)  NOT NULL,
    CreatedDateTime TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    Etcetera        CHAR(30)  NOT NULL,  
    --
    CONSTRAINT UserProfile_PK         PRIMARY KEY (UserId),
    CONSTRAINT UserProfile_AK         UNIQUE      (Username),
    CONSTRAINT UserProfileToPerson_FK FOREIGN KEY (UserId)
        REFERENCES Person (PersonId)  
);

CREATE TABLE Account (
    AccountNumber   INT       NOT NULL,
    OwnerPartyId    INT       NOT NULL, -- A role name assigned to PartyId in order to depict the meaning it carries in the context of an Account.
    CreatedDateTime TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    Etcetera        CHAR(30)  NOT NULL,  
    --
    CONSTRAINT Account_PK        PRIMARY KEY (AccountNumber),
    CONSTRAINT AccountToParty_FK FOREIGN KEY (OwnerPartyId)
        REFERENCES Party (PartyId)
);

CREATE TABLE Transfer (
    TransferorAccountNumber INT       NOT NULL, -- Role name assigned to AccountNumber.
    TransfereeAccountNumber INT       NOT NULL, -- Role name assigned to AccountNumber
    TransferDateTime        TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,  
    Amount                  INT       NOT NULL, -- Retains the Amount in Cents, but there are other possibilities.
    Etcetera                CHAR(30)  NOT NULL, 
    --
    CONSTRAINT Transfer_PK             PRIMARY KEY (TransferorAccountNumber, TransfereeAccountNumber, TransferDateTime), -- Composite PRIMARY KEY.
    CONSTRAINT TransferToTransferor_FK FOREIGN KEY (TransferorAccountNumber)
        REFERENCES Account (AccountNumber),
    CONSTRAINT TransferToTransferee_FK FOREIGN KEY (TransfereeAccountNumber)
        REFERENCES Account (AccountNumber),
    CONSTRAINT AccountsAreDistinct_CK  CHECK       (TransferorAccountNumber <> TransfereeAccountNumber),
    CONSTRAINT AmountIsValid_CK        CHECK       (Amount > 0)
);
```

As noted, there is no need for the retention of ambiguous and problematic NULL marks in the columns of any of the base tables.

If you want to know if an *Account* involved in a certain *Transfer* is owned by an *Organization* or a *Person*, you can derive such information in a single SELECT statement via, e.g., the `Transfer.TrasnferorAccountNumber`, the `Account.PartyId`, and the `Party.PartyTypeCode` columns.

So that you can ensure that a *Party* can own at most one *Account* (as stated in comments), then you should fix a UNIQUE constraint for the `Account.PartyId` column. However, in real world scenarios, e.g., in a bank, a *Person* can own zero-one-or-many *Accounts*, thus I esteem that a one-to-zero-or-one association does not appear realistic.

As previously mentioned, the approach proposed in this answer is supposed to be utilized as a reference that you can extend and adapt on your own. Naturally, extensions and adaptations made at the conceptual level should be reflected in the logical model.

I tested the declaration of this structure in (i) [this db<>fiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=b57ea94718fe7a7ac95e9669c1733b27) and in (ii) [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/6cb5d), both running on PostgreSQL 9.6 (you initially attached the tag of this database management system).

**Integrity and consistency considerations regarding the tables Party, Person and Organization**

With the layout described above, one must guarantee that *each* “supertype” row is *at all times* complemented by its corresponding “subtype” counterpart and, in turn, ensure that said “subtype” row is compatible with the value contained in the supertype “discriminator” column.

It would be very handy and elegant to enforce such circumstances declaratively but, unfortunately, none of the major SQL platforms has provided the proper mechanisms to do so (as far as I know). Therefore, it is quite convenient to make use of [ACID TRANSACTIONS](http://amturing.acm.org/info/gray_3649936.cfm#add_1) so that these conditions are always confidently met in a database.

## Similar scenarios

In case you are interested in other business domains in which supertype-subtype structures come about, you might like to see my answers to

- “[Modeling a scenario in which each Music Artist is either a Group or a Solo Performer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/102069/63644)”,
- “[Advice on a basic design, first time database design](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/104619/63644)”, and
- “[How to model an entity type that can have different sets of attributes?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/149951/63644)”.

## Relevant resource

- [These Stack Overflow posts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15726535/4807879) cover very relevant points concerning the data type of a column that holds a *currency* datum, like `Transfer.Amount`, in PostgreSQL.

---

## Endnote

<sub><sup>**†**</sup> *Integration Definition for Information Modeling* ([IDEF1X](http://www.idef.com/idef1x-data-modeling-method/)) is a highly recommendable data modeling technique that was established as a *standard* in december 1993 by the United States *National Institute of Standards and Technology* (NIST). It is solidly based on (a) some of the early theoretical works authored by the originator of the relational model, i.e., [Dr. E. F. Codd](http://amturing.acm.org/award_winners/codd_1000892.cfm); on (b) the [Entity-Relationship view](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=320440), developed by [Dr. P. P. Chen](http://awards.acm.org/award_winners/chen_6196475.cfm); and also on (c) the Logical Database Design Technique, created by Robert G. Brown.</sub>

Comment: That was exactly was I was looking for! Your solution is better than RDFozz's since you provided more concise answer and accounts are in a separate table and allows future separation from database if necessary. I'll mark this answer as accepted. Both of you and RDFozz have my thanks.

Comment: This is the most eloquent and thorough post I've ever read, on any platform, ever. Wow. Great resources to boot.

Comment: @SeaDude Thanks a lot for your kind words. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the account table doesn't appear to change the fundamental issue.

In TransferHistory, you could have TransferFrom and TransferFromType, where TransferFrom is either a Member or an Organization ID value, and TransferFromType is "M" or "O". You can't use foreign keys at all here, and would have to maintain referential integrity "manually" (for instance, with triggers). Same for TransferTo.

A query would look something like this (replace with actual fields as needed):

```
SELECT COALESCE(of.OrgName, mf.MemberName) as "From"
      ,COALESCE(ot.OrgName, mt.MemberName) as "To"
      ,th.*
  FROM TransferHistory th
         LEFT JOIN Organization ot ON (th.TransferTo = ot.ID AND th.TransferToType = 'O')
         LEFT JOIN Member mt ON (th.TransferTo = mt.ID AND th.TransferToType = 'M')
         LEFT JOIN Organization of ON (th.TransferFrom = of.ID AND th.TransferFromType = 'O')
         LEFT JOIN Member mf ON (th.TransferFrom = mf.ID AND th.TransferFromType = 'M')
;
```

Or, you have 4 fields, `TransferFromMember`, `TransferFrom Org`, TransferToMember`and`TransferToOrg`, all foreign keys, and use constraints to ensure only one From and one To is set.

A query would look something like this (replace with actual fields as needed):

```
SELECT COALESCE(of.OrgName, mf.MemberName) as "From"
      ,COALESCE(ot.OrgName, mt.MemberName) as "To"
      ,th.*
  FROM TransferHistory th
         LEFT JOIN Organization ot ON (th.TransferToOrg = ot.ID)
         LEFT JOIN Member mt ON (th.TransferToMember = mt.ID)
         LEFT JOIN Organization of ON (th.TransferFromOrg = of.ID)
         LEFT JOIN Member mf ON (th.TransferFromMember = mf.ID)
;
```