# How to make Event (like a Party) Sources mutually exclusive?

Tags: mysql, database-design, schema, erd, subtypes

I'm designing an entity-relationship diagram (ERD) for a marketplace of events. An event can be created by a user, in which case the `Event` table must have `owner_id` or we pull it from an API in which case the `Event` table must have `api_id`.

However, it can only be one way or the other. So, an event can be created by a user or pulled from API, never both.

How do I express `owner_id` and `api_id` as *mutually-exclusive* in ER diagram and how will it translate in tables?

This is the ERD I have developed so far:

[image]

Comment: A future visitor might find [*series of posts 1*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/179712/63644) and [*series of posts 2*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/102069/63644) (both about scenarios involving *supertype-subtype* structures) of help.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution to this is move the `API` entity up next to `Admin`, `User`, `Biz User`, and make a relationship `User` `ISA` (is a?) `API`.