# Designing a database for the academic activities of individuals or departments

Tags: mysql, database-design, schema

I have a database which stores the academic activities in which some individuals or departments are involved.
An activity could be any among some of these types:

- article (written)
- course (imparted)
- book (written)
- prize (received)
- project (developed)
- ...

and can involve a whole department (as an entity) or individuals (1 to n). It's a XOR, or departments or individuals, e.g.:

- an article is written by 1:n individuals, never by a department.
- a prize is received by a department, never by individuals.
- ...

Each Activity is defined by multiple **properties**: some are **common** to all types, some are **specific** for each type:

- **common properties**: title, description, year, valoration, ...
- **specific properties**:

  - for article: magazine, month, ISSN, URL,...
  - for course: institution, city, hours, course_type, ...
    ...

**¿What is the proper way to design the database?**
I came up with two ideas:

**A)** Isolate each type in one table with all columns it needs ( common and specific ). Each table manages its own ID, non unique between all activities.

[image]

Each table has its own relationship table with `individual` OR `department`.

**B)** One "master" table for common columns and primary ID, and one "child" table for the specific columns of each activity type:

[image]

Everything is shared unless its own specific columns.

Option **a)** seems proper way to do it, option **b)** seems ugly to me.

But in real world I prefer b). If I need a list of all activities in year 2017, a simple query to master is enough. If later I need a concrete activity, consulting very few tables I get all info (common + specific columns, individuals or department involved, etc).

**¿Is a bad practice to design the database thinking of my app requirements?** 
I need some advice here.

Comment: You may find of help [answer *a*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/102069/63644), [answer *b*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/179712/63644) and [answer *c*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/149951/63644); they are all about scenarios involving a conceptual structure known as *supertype-subtype*.

Comment: Thank you @MDCCL, that is what I was looking for. I just did not know how to name it. :S