# What is the correct way to organize tables for a SQL view?

Tags: join, schema, view, erd

I'm new to data modeling. Currently working at creating a personal contact manager but I need some help with modeling the table relationships for a given view.

**The final view columns I'm shooting for are:**

- orgName (that a PERSONAL_CONTACT belongs to)
- contFirstName
- contLastName
- phnNumber where phnType = "Primary"
- socHandle where socType = "Primary"
- emailAddress where emailType = "Primary"
- addrAddress where addrType = "Primary"

**The current ER diagram is:**
[image]

**This table setup doesn't look correct to me.**

Both `ORGANIZATIONS` and `PERSONAL_CONTACTS` can have their own `EMAIL`, `PHONE`, `SOCIAL` and `PHYSICAL_ADDRESSES`, but a `PERSONAL_CONTACT` can only exist in a single `ORGANIZATION`.

**Is this the correct way to organize these tables or am I approaching the relationships incorrectly?**

**EDIT 1: Based on @Akina 's input**
[image]

**EDIT 2:**
[image]

**EDIT 3:**

- This is where I ended up with the table schema
  [image]

Comment: *but a PERSONAL_CONTACT can only exist in a single ORGANIZATION.* This is easily provided by foreign key + NOT NULL condition. I do not see the incorrectness in this point.

Comment: But I see incorrectness in referencies to contact information. You must have independent tables for contacts and separate junction tables between objection (org., pers.) and contact tables. For example, the same address may be a contact for the organization (or even for 2 or more organizations) and for a lot of persons which belongs to this organization - current scheme does not provide this relation.

Comment: Thank you for the input. Do you mean I should break out the `xOrgGUID` and `xPersContactGUID` into bridge tables as shown in OP **EDIT 1** ?

Comment: I mean, you need to delete everything and start from the beginning. But first perform a complete analysis of the subject area. PS. Maybe "subject area" is not correct term - but I don't know how to translate the term from Russian more correctly.

Comment: I'm trying to analyze the space. Being new to data modeling, I'm looking for insights on which scenarios need to be covered. I think **EDIT 2** covers your scenario, right? I simplified the columns too to make things easier to communicate.

Comment: I believe now, an Org can have 1 or many Pers.Contacts. **Also** both Orgs and Pers.Contacts can have 1 or many individual contact types (Social, Email, Phone, Physical Address).

Comment: This looks like a way to EAV...

Comment: I'm not familiar with the term "EAV". Anyway, I found great guidance [on this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/179654/developing-a-database-for-a-funds-transfers-business-where-a-people-and-organi/179712?noredirect=1#comment567673_179712) on how to abstract the ORG and CONTACT away to a "PARTY". I think this in combination with the bridge tables should do fine.

Comment: *I'm not familiar with the term "EAV".* Entity-Attribute-Value pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Look at:

```
organization ( orgGUID PRIMARY KEY, 
               orgName, ... );

person ( personGUID PRIMARY KEY,
         orgGUID REFERENCES organization (orgGUID),
         personName, ... );

contact ( contactGUID PRIMARY KEY,
          contactValue,
          contactType ENUM ('address', 'phone', ...),
          additionalAttributes );

junction ( orgGUID REFERENCES organization (orgGUID),
           personGUID REFERENCES person (personGUID),
           contactGUID REFERENCES contact (contactGUID),
           additionalAttributes,
           CHECK (orgGUID  IS NULL or personGUID  IS NULL) );
```

Comment: Yours above is a good approach, but I'm not sure `contactType` is usable in this context. For example, if an `address` is selected, it will have `countryName`, `countryCode`, `state`, `city`, `streetName`, `houseNumber`, etc. If `phone` is selected, it will have completely different columns. A single `contact` table would have many `nulls`. I've broken each contact type into a unique table. Then using your concept of `junction` tables. Still need help on the view statement though. Please see **EDIT 3** if you can!

Comment: @SeaDude *For example, if an address is selected, it will have countryName, countryCode, state, city, streetName, houseNumber, etc.* In this case the value of `contactValue` must be a reference to Address tables chain (unique address point code which allows to define all mentioned parameters). *If phone is selected, it will have completely different columns.* ?? why? `contactValue` in this case stores the phone number, and `additionalAttributes` may store, for example, the marks "this is additional phone contact" and "call from 09-00 till 18-00 workdays only"...

Comment: Understood, ok. Very similar to what I ended up with above and the way MDCCL structured things in the post linked to earlier. Looks like we're in accord.