# Return results from SQL JOIN even if criteria not met in all tables

Tags: join, view

New to SQL. Building [my first contact manager project](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/290092/what-is-the-correct-way-to-organize-tables-for-a-sql-view/290327?noredirect=1#comment568108_290327). Current schema can be seen below.

**Issue:**

- I'm working on a view that shows all contact types (phone, email, socials, address) for a given contact.
- I put together the following attempt, but it only returns results if the `contactGUID` is in every contact_type table.

```
--Problem: Only returns records if contactGUID is present in every contact_type table

SELECT
c.contGUID, c.contType, 
i.indTitle, i.indFirstName, i.indMidName, i.indLastName, 
e.emailAddress, e.emailDomain,
p.phnCountryCode, p.phnAreaCode, p.phnNumber,
s.socURL, s.socHandle,
a.addrCountry, a.addrCountryCode, a.addrCountrySubdivision, a.addrCountrySubName, a.addrSecondarySubdiv, a.addrMunicipality, a.addrMuniSubdivision, a.addrStreetNumber, a.addrStreetName, a.addrPostalCode, a.addrLatitude, a.addrLongitude

FROM
CONTACT c

JOIN INDIVIDUALS i
ON c.contGUID = i.indGUID

JOIN CONTACT_EMAIL ce
ON c.contGUID = ce.contactGUID

JOIN EMAILS e
ON ce.emailGUID = e.emailGUID

JOIN CONTACT_PHONE cp
ON c.contGUID = cp.contactGUID

JOIN PHONES p
ON cp.phnGUID = p.phnGUID

JOIN CONTACT_SOCIAL cs
ON c.contGUID = cs.contactGUID

JOIN SOCIALS s
ON cs.socGUID = s.socGUID

JOIN CONTACT_PHYS_ADDRESS cpa
ON c.contGUID = cpa.contactGUID

JOIN PHYS_ADDRESSES a
ON cpa.addrGUID = a.addrGUID
```

**Question:**

- How do I return all other contact types (email, social, address) if say, `CONTACT_PHONE` record is not present for a given `contactGUID`?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Akina mentioned, you need to use an `OUTER JOIN`, specifically `LEFT OUTER JOIN` or more simply written as `LEFT JOIN` to take all the records from the left-hand side of the join clause, join where they match the right-hand side of the clause, and just `NULL` out the fields where they don't match in the right-hand side. This [tutorial from W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) gives a brief intro with visuals to the different join types. Here's another [article](http://www.sql-join.com/sql-join-types) with further information on different join types. (Note these articles are database-agnostic and there may be other available join types for your specific system as well, but these are generally all one ever needs.)

What you were previously doing by just specifying `JOIN` is using the shorthand syntax for the `INNER JOIN` clause which **only** returns rows that match on both sides of the join clause.